# Google Chrome ActionBar swipe

Tags: android, google-chrome, gestures

In the latest version of Chrome for Android, they changed it so when you swap pages instead of swiping from the edge, you swipe on the ActionBar / adreess bar.

Is there a way to do this with the native ActionBar or have they implmented their own that allows gestures?

Can someone please guide me in the right direction for implementing gestures on the ActionBar? Thanks!

Edit: I didn't find a way to access the native actionbar or find a way of hacking actionbarsherlock. So in summary, I didn't come up with a way of making this work.

Comment: What gestures you want to add on your action bar?? Like pull avtionbar to refresh??

Comment: I want to swipe across, exactly like how Chrome swipes to the side to swap "tabs" or webpages.

Answer (score 0):

I would experiment with extending the ViewPager and only pass touch events to the ViewPager's super method when the touch start occurs in a certain portion of the screen, otherwise pass the events to the platform to handle child view touch behaviour.

Comment: ViewPagers don't have access to the ActionBar unfortunately.

Comment: Chrome is most likely not using the ActionBar and using a custom view, I was assuming you would do the same.

Comment: That's what I suspected. I didn't want to "experiment" until I knew that I wasn't reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Definitely not reinventing the wheel :)